# Python Turtle Maze Crashing

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, maze

Conceptually, from what I've gathered online and in class, this should work to make a maze then allow the user to pilot the turtle through it to collect the gold circle at the end without being able to go through walls. But after I added the collision code, it creates the maze and places the goal but the turtle then becomes unresponsive and crashes. Any fixes?

```
import turtle
import math

turtle.setup(1000,1000)
window=turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor('white')

def forward():
    print("Key Up")
    turtle1.forward(10)
def right():
    print("Right")
    turtle1.right(90)    
def left():
    print("Left")
    turtle1.left(90)
def backward():
    print("Backward")
    turtle1.backward(10)

def iscollision(t1, t2):
    d = math.sqrt(math.pow(t1.xcor()-t2.xcor(),2)+ math.pow(t1.ycor()-t2.ycor(),2))
    if d < 20:
        return True
    elif():
        return False   
window.listen()

#boarders
boarder=turtle.Turtle()
boarder.penup()
boarder.setposition(-450,-450)
boarder.pendown()
boarder.pensize(10)
boarder.pencolor('black')

for side in range(4):
    boarder.speed(100)
    boarder.forward(900)
    boarder.left(90)
boarder.hideturtle()

#Maze
Maze=turtle.Turtle()
Maze.pensize(10)
#Speed
Maze.speed(100)
#Line 1
Maze.penup()
Maze.setposition(0,-450)
Maze.pendown()
Maze.setposition(300,-450)
Maze.setposition(0,-450)
Maze.setposition(0,-250)
Maze.setposition(150,-250)
Maze.setposition(0,-250)
Maze.setposition(0,-50)
Maze.setposition(100,-50)
Maze.setposition(0,-50)
Maze.setposition(0,-450)
#Line 2
Maze.setposition(300,-450)
Maze.setposition(300,100)
Maze.setposition(300,150)
Maze.setposition(100,150)
Maze.setposition(300,150)
Maze.setposition(300,50)
Maze.setposition(100,50)
Maze.setposition(300,50)
Maze.setposition(300,-150)
Maze.setposition(100,-150)
Maze.setposition(300,-150)
Maze.setposition(300,-450)
#Line 3
Maze.setposition(450,-450)
Maze.setposition(450,450)
Maze.setposition(200,450)
Maze.setposition(200,400)
Maze.setposition(50,400)
Maze.setposition(50,350)
Maze.setposition(0,350)
Maze.setposition(0,400)
Maze.setposition(-200,400)
Maze.setposition(-200,350)
Maze.setposition(-275,350)
Maze.setposition(-275,400)
Maze.setposition(-275,250)

#Maze2
Maze2=turtle.Turtle()
Maze2.pensize(10)
#Speed
Maze2.speed(100)
#line 4
Maze2.penup()
Maze2.setposition(300,150)
Maze2.pendown()
Maze2.setposition(100,150)
Maze2.setposition(100,200)
Maze2.setposition(-200,200)
Maze2.setposition(-200,150)
Maze2.setposition(-350,150)
Maze2.setposition(-350,400)

#Maze3
Maze3=turtle.Turtle()
Maze3.pensize(10)
#Speed
Maze3.speed(100)
#line 5
Maze3.penup()
Maze3.setposition(-275,150)
Maze3.pendown()
Maze3.setposition(-275,0)
Maze3.setposition(-200,0)
Maze3.setposition(-200,50)
Maze3.setposition(-150,50)
Maze3.setposition(-150,100)
Maze3.setposition(-100,100)
Maze3.setposition(-100,150)
Maze3.setposition(-50,150)
Maze3.setposition(-100,150)
Maze3.setposition(-100,100)
Maze3.setposition(-150,100)
Maze3.setposition(-150,50)
Maze3.setposition(-200,50)
Maze3.setposition(-200,0)
Maze3.setposition(-275,0)
Maze3.setposition(-275,-150)
Maze3.setposition(-350,-150)
Maze3.setposition(-275,-150)
Maze3.setposition(-275,-250)
Maze3.setposition(-350,-250)
Maze3.setposition(-200,-250)
Maze3.setposition(-200,-350)
Maze3.penup()
Maze3.setposition(-300,-450)
Maze3.pendown()
Maze3.setposition(-300,-350)
Maze3.setposition(-300,-450)
Maze3.setposition(-100,-450)
Maze3.setposition(-100,-350)
Maze3.setposition(-100,-450)
Maze3.setposition(450,-450)
Maze3.setposition(450,250)
Maze3.setposition(200,250)
Maze3.setposition(450,250)
Maze3.setposition(450,450)
Maze3.setposition(300,450)
Maze3.setposition(300,300)
Maze3.setposition(300,350)
Maze3.setposition(350,350)
Maze3.penup()
Maze3.setposition(-450,0)
Maze3.pendown()
Maze3.setposition(-350,0)
Maze3.penup()
Maze3.setposition(0,-200)
Maze3.pendown()
Maze3.setposition(-100,-200)
Maze3.setposition(-100,-100)
Maze3.setposition(-150,-100)

#end goal
goal=turtle.Turtle()
goal.color('gold')
goal.shape('circle')
goal.penup()
goal.setposition(375,-350)

turtle1=turtle.Turtle()
turtle1.color('black')
turtle1.shape("turtle")
turtle1.penup()
turtle1.setposition(100,-300)
window.onkey(forward,"Up")
window.onkey(right,"Right")
window.onkey(left,"Left")
window.onkey(backward,"Down")
window.listen()

while True:
    #boundary check
    if turtle1.xcor()> 450 or turtle1.xcor()< -450:
        turtle1.right(180)
    if turtle1.ycor()> 450 or turtle1.ycor()< -450:
        turtle1.right(180)     
##    if iscollision(turtle1, goal):
##        goal.hideturtle()
##    if iscollision(turtle1, Maze):
##        turtle1.right(180)
##    if iscollision(turtle1, Maze2):
##        turtle1.right(180)
##    if iscollision(turtle1, Maze3):
##        turtle1.right(180)
```

Comment: Why do you have two `window.listen()` calls?

Answer (score 0):

> after I added the collision code, it creates the maze and places the
>   goal but the turtle then becomes unresponsive

The problem is you added an infinite loop, `while True:`, to the turtle code which means it will never run `mainloop()` and turtle events won't fire off.  In this case the solution is simple, make boundary check a normal function, without the inifinite loop, and just call it from `forward()` and `backward()`, i.e. whenever the turtle moves.

I've made the above change and some style tweaks below.  You should be able to move your turtle again.  However, although your border collision detection is fine, as is your goal detection, I don't believe your maze wall detection will work with the strategy you're currenly persuing:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import math

def forward():
    turtle_1.forward(10)
    boundary_check()

def right():
    turtle_1.right(90)

def left():
    turtle_1.left(90)

def backward():
    turtle_1.backward(10)
    boundary_check()

def iscollision(t1, t2):
    d = math.sqrt((t2.xcor() - t1.xcor()) ** 2 + (t2.ycor() - t1.ycor()) ** 2)
    return d < 20.0

def draw_wall(turtle, positions):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(positions[0])
    turtle.pendown()
    for position in positions[1:]:
        turtle.setposition(position)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1000, 1000)
screen.bgcolor('white')

screen.onkey(forward, "Up")
screen.onkey(right, "Right")
screen.onkey(left, "Left")
screen.onkey(backward, "Down")
screen.listen()

# border
border = Turtle(visible=False)
border.penup()
border.pensize(10)
border.pencolor('black')
border.setposition(-450, -450)
border.pendown()
border.speed("fastest")

for _ in range(4):
    border.forward(900)
    border.left(90)

# Maze
maze_1 = Turtle(visible=False)
maze_1.pensize(10)
maze_1.speed("fastest")

wall_1 = [(0, -450), (300, -450), (0, -450), (0, -250), (150, -250), \
    (0, -250), (0, -50), (100, -50), (0, -50), (0, -450)]

draw_wall(maze_1, wall_1)

wall_2 = [(300, -450), (300, 100), (300, 150), (100, 150), (300, 150), \
    (300, 50), (100, 50), (300, 50), (300, -150), (100, -150), \
    (300, -150), (300, -450)]

draw_wall(maze_1, wall_2)

wall_3 = [(450, -450), (450, 450), (200, 450), (200, 400), (50, 400), \
    (50, 350), (0, 350), (0, 400), (-200, 400), (-200, 350), \
    (-275, 350), (-275, 400), (-275, 250)]

draw_wall(maze_1, wall_3)

maze_2 = Turtle(visible=False)
maze_2.pensize(10)
maze_2.speed("fastest")

wall_4 = [(300, 150), (100, 150), (100, 200), (-200, 200), \
    (-200, 150), (-350, 150), (-350, 400)]

draw_wall(maze_2, wall_4)

maze_3 = Turtle(visible=False)
maze_3.pensize(10)
maze_3.speed("fastest")

wall_5 = [(-275, 150), (-275, 0), (-200, 0), (-200, 50), (-150, 50), \
    (-150, 100), (-100, 100), (-100, 150), (-50, 150), (-100, 150), \
    (-100, 100), (-150, 100), (-150, 50), (-200, 50), (-200, 0), \
    (-275, 0), (-275, -150), (-350, -150), (-275, -150), (-275, -250), \
    (-350, -250), (-200, -250), (-200, -350)]

draw_wall(maze_3, wall_5)

wall_6 = [(-300, -450), (-300, -350), (-300, -450), (-100, -450), \
    (-100, -350), (-100, -450), (450, -450), (450, 250), (200, 250), \
    (450, 250), (450, 450), (300, 450), (300, 300), (300, 350), (350, 350)]

draw_wall(maze_3, wall_6)

wall_7 = [(-450, 0), (-350, 0)]

draw_wall(maze_3, wall_7)

wall_8 = [(0, -200), (-100, -200), (-100, -100), (-150, -100)]

draw_wall(maze_3, wall_8)

# end goal
goal = Turtle(shape='circle')
goal.color('gold')
goal.penup()
goal.setposition(375, -350)

turtle_1 = Turtle(shape='turtle')
turtle_1.color('black')
turtle_1.penup()
turtle_1.setposition(100, -300)

def boundary_check():
    # boundary check
    if not -450 < turtle_1.xcor() < 450 or not -450 < turtle_1.ycor() < 450:
        turtle_1.right(180)

    if iscollision(turtle_1, goal):
        goal.hideturtle()

    # if iscollision(turtle, maze_1):
    #   turtle_1.right(180)
    # if iscollision(turtle, maze_2):
    #   turtle_1.right(180)
    # if iscollision(turtle, maze_3):
    #   turtle_1.right(180)

screen.mainloop()
```